# How to set default value for configuration field with type time

Tags: magento2, configuration, default-values, time

How can I set a default value for a field from system.xml with type time?

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <section id="my_checkout" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Checkout</label>
        <tab>my_tab</tab>
        <resource>My_Checkout::config</resource>
        <group id="cut_off_time" translate="label" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Delivery Cut-off Time</label>
            <field id="cut_off_time_start" type="time" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Start Time</label>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

For field "cut_off_time_start" with type TIME.

Comment: Can you please upload your system.xml?

Comment: I added example system.xml in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this format:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <my_checkout>
            <cut_off_time>
                <cut_off_time_start>02,00,00</cut_off_time_start>
            </cut_off_time>
        </my_checkout>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: @Jeka Does it works for you?

Comment: I tried  separate by "." and ":" but correctly separate by ",".

Comment: @Jeka Glad to hear it. If my answer has been helpful, please, accept it

Comment: One thing to be noted is that It did not work when I was using `time` as the field ID. It worked after I changed it to `start_time`.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :** create file in this location for creating configuration fields –

> app/code///etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
  <section id="payment">
      <group id="wkmodule" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
          <label><![CDATA[Test Payment Module]]></label>                  
          <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="101" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
              <label>Enabled</label>
              <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
          </field>
      </group>
  </section>
```

**Step 2 :** Create file to set default values here :

> app/code///etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <payment>
        <wkmodule>
            <active>0</active>
            <------>x</---->
        </wkmodule>
    </payment>
</default>
```

For more reference [Click here](https://webkul.com/blog/set-default-configuration-values-magento-2/)

Comment: I know how to set the default value for the "select" and the "text", but I do not know how to do it for the "time".

Comment: How to set multi-select default all value?